# Making a label visible on form1 from form2 VB

Tags: vb.net, forms, communication

I'm writing a application where a user will be logged in. (Form2 Login)
And it needs to make a label appear on the main form.
Currently I have this code:

```
 Form1.Label1.Visible = True
```

And this doesn't work. It doesn't need to handle multiple usernames it just needs to show the label as a PoC.

Comment: Add `Form`.Show()`, decent odds that you'll now see it.  And to realize that you posted the wrong snippet in your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can set modifiers of label to public.
2. Change declaration of label from private to protected.
3. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980412/change-textbox-text-parent-from-child-form) If you have problems translating just ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class mainform
Private Sub mainform_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    loginform.Show()
label1.visible=false
End sub
End class

Public Class loginform
Private Sub ButtonLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonLogin.Click
    mainform.Label1.Visible = True
End sub
End class
```

This has to work!